# http url input parameters

Tags: http, url

Is this a valid http url

http://www.example.com?x&y

or

we must always have = sign for parameters.

http://www.example.com?x1=x&x2=y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it works, and the W3C recommendations are extremely general -- only the use of ? and + are defined. So I think from the perspective of HTTP/HTML the = is optional. It's use is obviously a common convention and many client & server libraries use it, but there doesn't seem to be any reason you couldn't define a service to work on some other scheme.

Anecdotally, I like to leave out the =blah part when I'm using the query string as a flag as in http://www.example.com?logout

Reference: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the ABNF in Appendix A of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), both examples above are valid URL.

Note that if you read only the Wikipedia article on [Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), you might get the false impression that the second ne is the only valid one.